# Resolving an apparent contradiction between Schwarzschild and ingoing Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

I believe this is basic differential geometry issue. This may be obvious to many, but I was quite confused about it, and it took me quite a while to find the resolution. I'm going to ask and answer this myself, since I believe this kind of thing is encouraged.

I'm going to neglect the angular coordinates in the following, since they don't affect anything.

Consider the Schwarzschild metric. In Schwarzschild coordinates, we have

\begin{align*}
    ds^2 &= -f(r)dt^2 + \frac{1}{f(r)}dr^2.
\end{align*}

Where $f(r) = 1 - \frac{2M}{r}$.

We do a coordinate change to get ingoing Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates

\begin{align*}
    v &= t + r + 2M \log{\frac{r - 2M}{2M}}\\
    dv &= dt + \frac{dr}{f(r)},
\end{align*}

which gives

\begin{align*}
    ds^2 &= -f(r)dv^2 + 2 dv dr.
\end{align*}

Consider the vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$.

If we compute $g(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial}{\partial r})$ in Schwarzschild coordinates, we get $g_{rr} = \frac{1}{f(r)}$. However if we compute $g(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial}{\partial r})$ in ingoing Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates, we seem to get $g_{rr} = 0$.

What is going on?

Answer (score 7):

It is not a contradiction at all, and goes back to the well-known and often-emphasized fact that partial derivatives depend on which coordinates you keep constant.

In general, if you have a function $f:M\to\Bbb{R}$ (i.e not your $f(r)$ particularly, but literally any smooth function on any smooth manifold), then you can define its exterior derivative $df$. So, the data of a single function $f$ immediately allows you to define a 1-form $df$. **However**, a single function $f$ does NOT (barring trivial cases like 1D manifolds with $df$ nowhere vanishing) in general give rise to a vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial f}$. Rather, you need the full information of a coordinate system $(U,(x^1,\dots, x^n))$ and from this entire coordinate chart you can construct $n$-different vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.

Note very carefully that the definition of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$ depends on not just the coordinate function $x^1:U\to\Bbb{R}$, but on the remaining $(n-1)$ functions $x^2,\dots, x^{n}:U\to\Bbb{R}$ as well (but like I said above, the exterior derivative $dx^1\equiv d(x^1)$ makes sense regardless of $x^2,\dots, x^n$). So, perhaps it might be better to write the notation as $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)_1$ or $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\right)_{(x^1,\dots, x^n)}$ rather than simply $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$ to indicate that it is the first vector field associated to the entire coordinate system $x=(x^1,\dots, x^n)$.

So, coming to the Schwarzschild vs Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates, you indeed have to be cautious of the coordinate $r$-vector field $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)_{(t,r,\theta,\phi)}$ associated to the Schwarzschild coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ vs the coordinate $r$-vector field $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)_{(v,r\theta,\phi)}$ associated to the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates $(v,r,\theta,\phi)$.

I want to stress this once again:

- the function $r$ makes sense all on its lonesome
- the exterior derivative $dr$ also makes sense all on its lonesome
- a vector field “$\partial_r=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$” DOES NOT make sense all on its own. You MUST specify the remaining coordinates (because they specify the things you keep constant).

[Here’s the same issue I emphasize in the thermodynamics context.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/774263/203278)

---

At the bare linear algebra level, you can already see this sort of single vs many dependence. Given a vector space $V$ and a non-zero vector $v$, I cannot speak of “the dual vector of $v$”. Rather, given an entire basis $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ for $V$, I can consider its dual basis $\{\epsilon^1,\dots, \epsilon^n\}$. However, if I change my original basis say I replace $e_1$ by some other $w_1$, and consider the basis $\{w_1,e_2,\dots, e_n\}$, then I will get a corresponding dual basis $\{\xi^1,\dots,\xi^n\}$, and even though I only changed the first vector in my basis for $V$, there is no reason to assume the same will be true for the dual bases, i.e it need not be true that $\epsilon^2=\xi^2,\dots, \epsilon^n=\xi^n$.

---

Just for fun, let’s do some more computations. In the other answer, you see how the $r$-coordinate derivatives are related. Let me show you how the $t$ and $v$-coordinate derivatives are related (slightly different presentation): It’s essentially the chain rule (as you see in the other answer), but here I’ll present it in a slightly different way (but ‘really’ it’s the same idea, just phrased using duality). In general, for any vector field $X$ and any coordinate system $(U,x=(x^1,\dots, x^n))$ we can write $X=(dx^i)(X)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)_{(x^1,\dots, x^n)}$. So applied in our case,
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)_{(t,r,\theta,\phi)}&=
dv\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)_{(t,r,\theta,\phi)}\right) \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)_{(v,r,\theta,\phi)}\\
&+
dr\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)_{(t,r,\theta,\phi)}\right) \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)_{(v,r,\theta,\phi)}\\
&+
d\theta\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)_{(t,r,\theta,\phi)}\right) \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)_{(v,r,\theta,\phi)}\\
&+
d\phi\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)_{(t,r,\theta,\phi)}\right) \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\right)_{(v,r,\theta,\phi)}
\end{align}
The second, third, and fourth terms are $0$, because we’re applying a $dx^j$ 1-form on the vector field $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)_{(x^1,\dots, x^n)}$ with $i\neq j$. For the first term, we note that $dv=dt+\frac{dr}{f(r)}$, so we get
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)_{(t,r,\theta,\phi)}&=
\left(dt+\frac{dr}{f(r)}\right)\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)_{(t,r,\theta,\phi)}\right) \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)_{(v,r,\theta,\phi)}\\
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{f(r)}\cdot 0\right)\cdot \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)_{(v,r,\theta,\phi)}\\
&= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)_{(v,r,\theta,\phi)}
\end{align}
Hence, $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)_{(t,r,\theta,\phi)} = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)_{(v,r,\theta,\phi)} $. This is all the more a trippy result to think about ‘naively/intuitively’ especially when you consider that the level sets of the $t$ coordinate function are spacelike hypersurfaces, whereas the level sets of the $v$-coordinate function are null hypersurfaces. Anyway, what this shows is the striking difference between vector fields, 1-forms, exterior derivatives and gradient vector fields and their difference (and why you MUST be careful of their difference, and this isn’t just mathematical mumbo-jumbo for its own sake).

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that in general coordinate induced vector fields depend on all of the coordinates. For example, suppose we have coordinates $x, y, z$, and we change to $u, v, w$. Then even if the coordinate change is such that, say "$x = u$",  it does not follow that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$. It is perhaps sloppy notation, although understandable, to use $r$ as a coordinate label in both coordinate systems above.

If we are more careful about our change of variables, we could say that in Scharzschild coordinates we have, as before

\begin{align*}
    ds^2 &= -f(r)dt^2 + \frac{1}{f(r)}dr^2.
\end{align*}

And as before $g(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}) = \frac{1}{f(r)}$.

Now we change coordinates, careful to distinguish the original $r$ coordinate from the new one $R$:

\begin{align*}
    v &= t + r + 2M \log{\frac{r - 2M}{2M}} \\
    R &= r.
\end{align*}

Thus

\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial }{\partial r} &= \frac{\partial v}{\partial r} \frac{\partial}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial R}{\partial r} \frac{\partial}{\partial R} \\
    &= \frac{1}{f(R)}\frac{\partial}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial}{\partial R}.
\end{align*}

So that

\begin{align*}
    g(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}) &= g(\frac{1}{f(R)}\frac{\partial}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial}{\partial R}, \frac{1}{f(R)}\frac{\partial}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial}{\partial R}) \\
    &= \frac{1}{(f(R))^2}g_{vv} + \frac{2}{f(R)}g_{vR} + g_{RR} \\
    &=  -\frac{1}{f(R)} + \frac{2}{f(R)} + 0\\
    &=\frac{1}{f(R)} \\
    &= \frac{1}{f(r)},
\end{align*}

and so we get the same answer as before.

Hopefully this will be of use to someone.

Comment: This is perhaps more easily understandable if you don't think geometrically - vectors are partial derivatives, and as we know from thermodynamics, the variable that is held constant also matters.